# MySQL 1356 error when I try to execute View Saved Routine when moving to new server

Tags: mysql, view

I have moved a MySQL database along with several procedures.  All of the procedures are working except one that is critical to my application.  It sets up the views that I need to work the primary application.  I am fairly new to mysql views.

Here is the procedure code that is working on the original server:

```
BEGIN  
     UPDATE rdi AS r
     INNER JOIN vw_ytd_permits_by_builder_sf v_ytd ON r.company = v_ytd.company
     AND r.city = v_ytd.city
     AND r.state = v_ytd.state
     AND r.zip = v_ytd.zip
     SET r.ytd_permits = v_ytd.ytd_permits, r.ytd_value = v_ytd.ytd_value
     WHERE r.project_type LIKE 'SINGLE%';

     UPDATE rdi AS r
     LEFT JOIN vw_ytd_permits_by_builder_sf v_ytd ON r.company = v_ytd.company
     AND r.city = v_ytd.city
     AND r.state = v_ytd.state
     AND r.zip = v_ytd.zip
     SET r.ytd_permits = 0, r.ytd_value = 0
     WHERE v_ytd.company IS NULL AND r.project_type LIKE 'SINGLE%';

     UPDATE rdi AS r
     INNER JOIN vw_12mth_prev_permits_by_builder_sf v_12p on r.company = v_12p.company
     AND r.city = v_12p.city
     AND r.state = v_12p.state
     AND r.zip = v_12p.zip
     SET r.12mth_prev_permits = v_12p.12mth_prev_permits
     WHERE r.project_type LIKE 'SINGLE%';

     UPDATE rdi AS r
     INNER JOIN vw_ytd_permits_by_builder_mf v_ytd ON r.company = v_ytd.company
     AND r.city = v_ytd.city
     AND r.state = v_ytd.state
     AND r.zip = v_ytd.zip
     SET r.ytd_permits = v_ytd.ytd_permits, r.ytd_value = v_ytd.ytd_value
     WHERE r.project_type LIKE 'MULTI%';

     UPDATE rdi AS r
     LEFT JOIN vw_ytd_permits_by_builder_mf v_ytd ON r.company = v_ytd.company
     AND r.city = v_ytd.city
     AND r.state = v_ytd.state
     AND r.zip = v_ytd.zip
     SET r.ytd_permits = 0, r.ytd_value = 0
     WHERE v_ytd.company IS NULL AND r.project_type LIKE 'MULTI%';

     UPDATE rdi AS r
     INNER JOIN vw_12mth_prev_permits_by_builder_mf v_12p on r.company = v_12p.company
     AND r.city = v_12p.city
     AND r.state = v_12p.state
     AND r.zip = v_12p.zip
     SET r.12mth_prev_permits = v_12p.12mth_prev_permits
     WHERE r.project_type LIKE 'MULTI%';

END
```

Comment: Can you add the missing lines (i.e. DROP and CREATE) that should be above the BEGIN line?

Comment: What versions of mysql are you on old and new server? AND can you add the view code.AND what do you mean by not working - do you get a syntax error or does it not update or does it not update as expected.

Comment: Original version is 5.5.31 moving to 5.7.26
When I add in 
DROP PROCEDURE `set_ytd_and_12mth_prev_sp`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `set_ytd_and_12mth_prev_sp`()
    COMMENT 'Updates ytd_permits, ytd_value and 12mth_prev_permits columns'

I get a different error 
There are no results for One or more errors have occurred while processing your request: The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `set_ytd_and_12mth_prev_sp`() COMMENT 'Updates ...' NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER DROP PROCEDURE

Comment: I get the 1356 error and it halts execution.